# How to send mplfinance candle stick chart to frontend using flask?

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, mplfinance

I'm working on the flask project where I use the mplfinance library to create candlestick charts and I need to pass this chart to the frontend.

```html
@app.route('/chartdata', methods =['POST'])
def chart_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        body = request.json
        df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
        df.index.name = 'Date'
        mplfinance.plot(df, type = 'candle',style ='yahoo',savefig ="sample.png")
        
        return "image to transferred"
```

I tried this approach of saving the image and passing it to the front but here I can't avoid chart plot opening, Does anyone knows a better way to transfer these charts to the frontend Html page in this flask project

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this has been solved, but here for posterity.

The important part is to set the backend to use a non-gui method.  Also make sure to use `send_file` do deal with sending back the buffer and filename.  These same strategies for for normal matplotlib, just substitute the filename with the `io.BytesIO` and it will handle it automatically.  It seems the python trend is to have it accept a filename, or some sort of stream interface.

This should be a rough approximation of what is desired.

```py
# Use buffer to save object
from io import BytesIO

# Set the matplotlib to a no display backend
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')

import mplfinance

@app.route('/chartdata', methods =['POST'])
def chart_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = request.json
        df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
        df.index.name = 'Date'

        # The buffer the figure will save to instead of a filename.
        memory_file = BytesIO()
        mplfinance.plot(df, type = 'candle',style ='yahoo',savefig=dict(fname=memory_file, format="png"))

        # seek to the beginning to the buffer because send_file will start at the current io position. 
        memory_file.seek(0)

        # send the file back to the user as an attachment 
        # so it will prompt to download.
        return send_file(memory_file, download_name="sample.png", as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save your figure to a `io.BytesIO` object and send it to the frontend, like here https://mellowd.dev/python/using-io-bytesio/

`mplfinance.plot(...)` has a `savefig` parameter for that, see https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/src/mplfinance/plotting.py#L171

Something like below, needs to be tested, as mplfinance.plot() does not have a keyword for image format.

```
import io

@app.route('/chartdata', methods =['POST'])
def chart_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        body = request.json
        df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
        df.index.name = 'Date'
        b = io.BytesIO()
        mplfinance.plot(df, type = 'candle',style ='yahoo', savefig=b)
        return b
```

Comment: The first example  you mentioned does not uses matplotlib sir, In the second one how can i use the Bytesio instances in savefig parameter sir? will you give a short code ?

Comment: This will fail quite often if you run it from a server with:  `UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.`

Comment: Bah!  The -1 was by mistake, the above is not wrong, just incomplete.